# Using last number from the first 4 numbers to fetch users details from MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

If I have digits like this(account numbers actually).

```
200101
200201
```

**200201** is for saving account while 200101 is a current account.My main goal is to fetch all details of users with acount that start with `2001` from mysql. How can I manipulate number like this in MySQL to pull out the users details?

Comment: you can use left, substring functon ..it all up to you ..there are mutliple options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the account number is a string, then use:

```
where accountnum like '2001%'
```

If it is a number, then I presume you want to lop off the last two digits.  For that, use division:

```
where floor(accountnum / 100) = 2001
```

I don't recommend using string functions on numbers and vice versa.